# JQuery validation for checkbox

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

I know many can say that this is duplicate question , but i tried all option and no luck...
i'm having a form for which it has around 25 checkbox and on submit, the validation should check for atleast one to select

this is my checkbox element...

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check[]" value="4"> 
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check[]" value="5">
```

this is my jquery:

```
 <script>

 jQuery(".exportSelected").click(function(){
    $('#export').prop('checked', true);

    var checkedAtLeastOne = false; 
     if($('.check').prop( "checked" )==true)
     {
      checkedAtLeastOne == true;
     }        

    if (checkedAtLeastOne == true) {
     jQuery(".submitDel").trigger("click"); 
     }
     else {
    alert ("Atleast select one to Export")
    }  
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return number of checkbox checked :

```
 $("input.check:checked").length
```

Just give below condition like to check more than one check box checked :

```
if( $("input.check:checked").length > 0) {
 //Your Code
}
```

Also, You need to trigger `Click event` after the `Document ready` Event.

[** DEMO Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/489Y2/8/)

Hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: You must handle click event under ready event. I update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Use `length`  to find no. of selected check box .if it zero none of them selected

```
jQuery(".exportSelected").click(function(){
            if($('.check:checked').length>0){  // to check if check box checked more then one
              $(".submitDel").trigger("click"); 
            }else{
             alert ("Atleast select one to Export")
            }
}
```